# frequently update QLabel with image data from server

Tags: qt, sockets, qwidget, qthread, synchronization

i am writing a program, that should show an image in `QLabel` in a `QWidget`. The images are sent from the server. First, I have a thread that is responsible for the connection and receiving data from the server. When the data is received, the socket thread sends a signal `gotNewData(Imagedata)`, that is connected to the `QWidget` `updateImage(Imagedata)` slot. In the `updateImage(Imagedata)` slot I convert the image data, which I get from the server into `QImage`, scale image and create `QPixmap`, that I set to the `QLabel`. My problem is, during the processing `updateImage(Imagedata)` function the socket gets other packages with new images and sends the signal to the `QWidget` again and again. It's logical, because the socket thread doesn't care if the function `updateImage(Imagedata)`, that was invoked by the previous signal call, has finished already or not. My question is: is there some techniques, how I can synchronize my socket thread with `QWidget` `updateImage(Imagedata)` function?

Answer (score 0):

There definitely are. Question is what exactly do you want to achieve in case that new image is recieved while old one is still processed. If you want to skip new one and process old till the end, I would reccomend calling blockSignals on sending object - that destroys the caller and calle spearation, but qt doesn't seem to allow to block recieving signals, just sending.
Modification that wouldn't affect perfomance much, and would not confuse other comunication networking thred might get done, would be to create proxy QObject in widget containing the label, then using moveToThread() to move it to networking thread, and use blockSignals on this object. Naturally this object needs a signal of equal signature as actual signal being sent. Created object, while with different thread affinity, would logically remain owned by GUI widget, and should be deleted by it.

Another approach is to create bool variable `processing` in your object, and set it to true if you are processing data. Just before setting it back to false you call `QCoreApplication::processEvents();` which proceses all events in event queue. In your slot you should check if `processing` vaiable is set and skip doing anything if it is. It is a simple and crude soultion, but it works. Note that if you have other event handlers calling `processEvents();` (eg. more than one label like that) in your GUI thread, some of labels might stop getting their data at all (freeze).

You might be tempted to use `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` to block networking thread from recieving anything before processing is done, but thats a bad idea for many different reasons (if you synchronize it like that then why do you need separate thread at all?)

Comment: I put socket in the thread, because the user should be able to use GUI. In my case, if the user press some button, some commands will be sent to the server. For sending commands I use other socket connection. That's why i put the image receiver socket in the thread, it should not block the user interaction with the program.

Comment: I meant 'if you would synchronize it like that then why would you need separate thread at all?` Anyway, first solution should be a good idea.